# Crashing when Dereferencing "char*", cannot compare strings

Tags: c, kernel, driver

I have been working all day on figuring out a problem with my driver, the problem seems to be if I dereference either of my strings (ProcessName, attachedName) it will crash my driver and the operating system.

edit: I forgot to post that the char* dereference returns NULL or nothing to strcmp, that's why it crashed or seemed to crash. It caused or was caused by, a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION ntstatus. Hope that helps.

I have looked through everything I could find on google related to string comparison, multi-byte vs Unicode encoding, the difference between string types, and it eventually led me to realize if I dereferenced the variables it would cause the crash.

```c
// the callback, it is where I am trying to compare the strings
PCREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE Callback(HANDLE ParentId, HANDLE ProcessId, BOOLEAN Create) {
    if (Create == TRUE) {
        PEPROCESS Process;

        if (NT_SUCCESS(PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ProcessId, &Process))) {
            LPSTR ProcessName = (LPSTR)PsGetProcessImageFileName(Process);
            PVOID ProcessBase = PsGetProcessSectionBaseAddress(Process);
            UINT64 VirtualSize = (UINT64)((PCUCHAR)Process + 0x338);
            UINT64 PeakVirtualSize = (UINT64)((PCUCHAR)Process + 0x330);

            //if (attachedName) {
                //if (!strcmp(ProcessName, attachedName)) {
                    DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "ParentId: %i | ProcessId: %i | ProcessName: %s | ProcessBase: 0x%p | VirtualSize: 0x%X | PeakVirtualSize: 0x%X", ParentId, ProcessId, *ProcessName, ProcessBase, VirtualSize, PeakVirtualSize);
                //}
            //}

            ObDereferenceObject(Process);
        }
    }
}

// the case in a switch statement I call to be able to find a specific process in the callback

case IO_CTL_ATTACH:
    attachedName = sent->attach.exeName;
    DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "%s", attachedName);
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
```

The expected result is supposed to be a single character or anything printed out of the dereference of "ProcessName" if I remove the dereference no crash occurs.

I found all of this out via a debug message forwarding me to nt!strcmp + 4C, which is where it dereferences String1, or the first input.

Comment: if `DbgPrintEx` is anything like `printf`, then the format specifier `%s` is used for a string, and expects a `char*` argument. To print a single char, perhaps use `%c` with a `char` instead?

Comment: Where are you getting `attachedName`? Is it a global? Global variables should not be used in drivers.

Comment: I dont want to print a specific character, if you read anything you would have figured out I am trying to compare two strings. AttachedName happens to be global if you have a better idea to share attachedName from an ioctl to the callback let me know.

Comment: "The expected result is supposed to be a single character...". Fooled me. If there's no kernel `strcmp` you can easily roll your own.